# Get ajax post data from another module in plugin

Tags: module, ajax, form

is it possible to catch ajax post data from another module in my plugin?

I'm using SimpleForm2 https://allforjoomla.ru/extensions/mod-simpleform2

So this module creates a form and pass post data via ajax to internal index.php file.

In my plugin i want to catch this post data but when i try to get

```
$get_post = $_POST;
//or
$get_post = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

on onAfterInitialise() event in my plugin, I always get empty arrays.

Comment: Can you share the code for your ajax request?

Comment: Need more information to answer it. For example: SimpleForm2 has his own plugin system? And the AJAX, can you give some tips about the receptor of the information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Direct request into plugin method using `com_ajax` (https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface), that keeps your flow inside framework as well gives you a bit more security.